# Java functional approach to join identical elements into a single one

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I would like to use Streams API to process a call log and calculate the total billing amount for the same phone number. Here's the code that achieves it with a hybrid approach but I would like to use fully functional approach:

```
List<CallLog> callLogs = Arrays.stream(S.split("\n"))
                    .map(CallLog::new)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(callLog -> callLog.phoneNumber))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (int i = 0; i< callLogs.size() -1 ;i++) {
                if (callLogs.get(i).phoneNumber == callLogs.get(i+1).phoneNumber) {
                    callLogs.get(i).billing += callLogs.get(i+1).billing;
                    callLogs.remove(i+1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should probably just group first then just combine all groups

Comment: One note - I *highly* suggest you don't treat phone numbers as an Integer type. Here is a rule of thumb - unless you're going to perform mathematical operations with the data, don't treat it as a number. Even if it's composed of only numeric members. Be that a phone number, account number, or whatever. If the "number" starts with zeroes, they'd be lost when converting to an actual numeric type, so account number `0001234` is not just `1234` which is *not* the same thing. Moreover, you are vulnerable to integer overflows - especially with phone numbers with large digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save yourself the sorting -> collection to list -> iterating the list for values next to each other if you instead do the following

1. Create all `CallLog` objects.
2. Merge them by the `phoneNumber` field

   - combine the `billing` fields every time
3. Return the already merged items

This can be done using [Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) where the third parameter is the merge function that defines how items with identical keys would be combined:

```java
Collection<CallLog> callLogs = Arrays.stream(S.split("\n"))
  .map(CallLog::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap( //a collector that will produce a map
    CallLog::phoneNumber,    //using phoneNumber as the key to group
    x -> x,                  //the item itself as the value
    (a, b) -> {              //and a merge function that returns an object with combined billing
      a.billing += b.billing;
      return a;
    }))
  .values(); //just return the values from that map
```

In the end, you would have `CallLog` items with unique `phoneNumber` fields whose `billing` field is equal to the combination of all `billing`s of the previously duplicate `phoneNumber`s.

Comment: This is what I definitely needed for following processing I didn't mention. Thank you for your answer and other suggestions/comments @vlaz

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) to group `CallLog` object by phoneNumber with [Collectors.summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to sum the billing of grouped elements

```
Map<Integer, Integer> likesPerType = Arrays.stream(S.split("\n"))
                                           .map(CallLog::new)
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CallLog::getPhoneNumber, Collectors.summingInt(CallLog::getBilling)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = Arrays.stream(S.split("\n"))
                    .map(CallLog::new)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(callLog -> callLog.phoneNumber))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        c -> c.phoneNumber(),
                        c -> c.billing(),
                        (a, b) -> a+b
                     ));
```

And if you want to have a 'List callLogs' as a result:

```
List<CallLog> callLogs = Arrays.stream(S.split("\n"))
                        .map(CallLog::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            c -> c.phoneNumber(),
                            c -> c.billing(),
                            (a, b) -> a+b
                         ))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(entry -> toCallLog(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(callLog -> callLog.phoneNumber))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the billing amount by phoneNumber, like VLAZ said. An example implementation could look something like this:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String s = "555123456;12.00\n"
                + "555123456;3.00\n"
                + "555123457;1.00\n"
                + "555123457;2.00\n"
                + "555123457;5.00";

        final Map<Integer, Double> map = Arrays.stream(s.split("\n"))
                .map(CallLog::new)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CallLog::getPhoneNumber, Collectors.summingDouble(CallLog::getBilling)));

        map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%d: %.2f\n", key, value));
    }

    private static class CallLog {

        private final int phoneNumber;
        private final double billing;

        public CallLog(int phoneNumber, double billing) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.billing = billing;
        }

        public CallLog(String s) {
            final String[] strings = s.split(";");
            this.phoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
            this.billing = Double.parseDouble(strings[1]);
        }

        public int getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public double getBilling() {
            return billing;
        }
    }
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
555123456: 15.00
555123457: 8.00
```

Comment: Yup. The sorted call is irrelevant once you use groupingBy.

Comment: You are right. I will remove it from my example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to remove duplicate phone numbers, while adding their billing. The one thing streams are incompatible with are remove operations. So how can we do what you need without remove?

Well instead of sorting I would go with [groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) phone numbers then I would map the list of groups of callLogs into callLogs with the billing already accumulated.